# display progressdialog in non-activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am trying to display a dialog in a non-Activity class. Basically, I detect an object in my app, I would like to display a dialog and then switch activities. I'm getting a "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" in my logcat.

Here is some of my code:

```
public ImageTargetsRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  }

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    testFlag = 0;

    // DO NOT RENDER IF THERE IS NO TRACKABLE
    if (!mIsActive)
        return;

    // Call our native function to render content
    // RENDER IF THERE IS A TRACKABLE
    testFlag = renderFrame();

    System.err.println("ImageTargetsRenderer reports: " + testFlag);

    if(testFlag > 0 && frameCount > 5)
    {
        frameCount = 0;
        System.err.println("Starting to switch activities.");

        mDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        mDialog.show();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                        try{
                            sleep(5000);
                        } catch (Exception e) { }
                // Dismiss the Dialog
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, FlashActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.flagTest", testFlag);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
        testFlag = 0; 

        return;
    }
    frameCount++;


}
```

Comment: Update the code in question after adding my edits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Dialog should be called from the UIthread so try to use this,

```
context.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Hope this works.

Comment: You have a context in this line of your code - this.context = context;

Comment: I added this: 

`new Thread() {
    public void run() {
     ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {  
       System.err.println("SHOW UP!");
       mDialog.show();
      }
     });
      try {
       sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      mDialog.dismiss();
   }
   };` but the dialog doesn't show?

Comment: This seems correct but you just for to start() the thread at last, do it.

Answer (score 1):

You do this

```
  context.runOnUIThread( new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                  // show the Dialog
                  mDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
                  mDialog.setMessage("Please wait");

                  mDialog.show();
               }
            });
         }

     Thread.sleep(5000);

        context.runOnUIThread( new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                  // Dismiss the Dialog
                  mDialog.dismiss();
               }
            });
```

Comment: Is this correct? `mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     // Dismiss the Dialog
                     mDialog.dismiss();
                  }
               });
            }
      }, 5000);`

Comment: I debugged it and found that the app crashes at mDialog.show() with the same looper.prepare error. Is there a way to use handler for show()?

Comment: show() also should be done in `runOnUIThread()` One for show() and one for dismiss().

Comment: How do I get the thread to sleep for 5 seconds? It seems like the 5000 at the 2nd argument of postDelayed isn't working. I don't see any dialog popup. Here is my code:    `mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 mDialog.show();
                 //SystemClock.sleep(5000);
                 mDialog.dismiss();
                  }
               });
        }
       }, 5000);`

Comment: You dont need to run another thread. Just run show dilog and dismiss dialog on UI thread. No need to start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exception you will get if you are performing any UI operation on any thread or from any background task. Also `context.runOnUiThread` won't work.

Instead use:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                             mDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                          });
```

You can use the same for showing where `activity` is the object of `activity`.