# How can I show a Dialog box from a thread other than the UI thread

Tags: java, android

My app requires gps reading, so on the main thread I start a Thread that reads the GPS but I'm having trouble showing a dialog that says "Please wait". I tied also using a Handler, but that didn't work either. What's the best to control the "Please wait" dialog from the 2nd Thread? Thanks!

```
public void showWaitDialog() {

    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    prgDialog.setTitle("Please wait.");
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    prgDialog.show();


}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can:

- Define an `Handler` in your UI Thread (e.g. in the `Activity`) and then pass it to your thread. Now from the thread you call `handler.post(runnable)` to enqueue code to be executed on the UIThread.
- Define a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` and from you thread send an `Intent` with the necessary information in the `Bundle`
- Use an `AsyncTask` and the methods `publishProgress`(), `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` to inform the `Activity` of the progress or when the taask has finished
- Use `runOnUiThread`.

It depends on your needs. For short-running asynchronous operations, `AsyncTask` is a good choice.

Comment: Hi I tried to pass the handler changing
`Thread myThread = new myClass();`
to
`Thread myThread = new myClass(handler);`
and then receiving it on the run() method, changing it to
`run(Handler handler);`
But that didn't work, what's the right way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you called handler.post(runnable)? You can edit your post and update it with code if it's still not working.

Comment: Yes, I did and it worked, but I didn't pass the handler, I just made it public on the Activity class and then used it from the Thread class calling it Activity.handler, but my question is how to pass the handler as arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an `AsyncTask`.  You can tell the Task on `onPreExecute()` to show the Please wait dialog, and then `onPostExecute(Result result)` you can remove the dialog.  Those two methods are working on the UI thread while `doInBackground(Params... params)` is occurring in a background thread.

Example:

```
private class GetGPSTask extends AsyncTask<null, null, null>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
                    showWaitDialog();  <-Show your dialog
    }


    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(null) {

                //your code to get your GPS Data
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    HideDialogbox(); <-Code to hide the dialog box
    }
}
```

Just remember to change the template types if you need to.  Where it says AsynTask , the first value is passed to `doInBackground`, 2nd value is for progress value, 3rd value is a return value from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have rightly suggested, you can preferably use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Here is an exampleof how to use it for your purpose: [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example). Otherwise you may use `runOnUiThread` method as well. From inside your second thread to make the changes on UI thread ( eg: Dialogs and Toasts). According to its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), it says:

`It runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.`

For eg;

```
Your_Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your stuff to update the UI
            showWaitDialog();

        }
    });
```

See [display progressdialog in non-activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201741/display-progressdialog-in-non-activity-class) and [Loading Dialog with runOnUiThread for update view on Android](http://sharecoding.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/simple-runonuithread-for-update-view-on-android/). 
hope this helps.